# Text file to JSON data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below mentioned text in a text file, Each key is present in a new line. I need to convert to a JSON data as mentioned below please can anyone help out on this issue.

Sample text file

```
name: Samuels heard
patient id :  7898
received date: 06/22/2019
firstname : scott deny 
dob : 06/22/2019
```

Required JSON data

```
{
  "name": "Samuels heard",
  "patient id": "7898",
  "received date": "06/22/2019",
  "firstname": "scott deny",
  "dob": "06/22/2019"
}
```

Comment: Open the file, read it line by line (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp). Split each line on `:`

Make the first part as key and second as value (dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
mydict = {}
with open("mytext.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
     mylst = line.rstrip('\n').split(":")
     mydict[mylst[0]] = mylst[1]


print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
 {'name': ' Samuels heard', 'patient id ': '  7898', 'received date': ' 06/22/2019', 'firstname ': ' scott deny', 'dob ': ' 06/22/2019'}
```